# boot user's personal system from NFS

Tags: networking, boot, nfs, clonezilla

In my university we have a computer room with PCs with Linux installed. At the login the user's home directory is mounted over NFS using login credentials.

I know that it is possible to boot the entire operating system over the network so that the PCs could have no disk at all.

I wonder if it would be possible to configure the boot process so that the user is asked the NFS credentials and the entire operating system is transferred from the user's home directory. This would allow users to have their own single user OS which they can configure as they like as administrators. Login/Logout would be replaced by shutdown and reboot.

Maybe clonezilla could be helpful?